# functional analysis, Schwartz space, $L^p(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, schwartz-space

> Is $1\leq p\leq\infty$ then holds every $g\in L^p(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$ the condition here: [linear, continuous functional, Schwartz space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523487/linear-continuous-functional-schwartz-space)

As hint is given, to use, that $x\mapsto \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Can you give me a further hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the trick that I showed you in another post:

\begin{align*}
\int|g(x)|^{p}dx&=\int|(1+|x|^{2})g(x)|^{p}\frac{1}{(1+|x|^{2})^{p}}dx\\
&\leq\left(\sup|(1+|x|^{2})g(x)|^{p}\right)\int\frac{1}{(1+|x|^{2})^{p}}dx\\
&\leq\left(\sup|(1+|x|^{2})g(x)|^{p}\right)\int\frac{1}{1+|x|^{2}}dx\\
&=\left(\sup|(1+|x|^{2})g(x)|\right)^{p}\int\frac{1}{1+|x|^{2}}dx
\end{align*}

For $p=\infty$ is easy.

Comment: So you showed the case $1\leq p<\infty$? Why is it easy for $p=\infty$?

Comment: Because you can choose the seminorm $\sup|g(x)|=\sup|(1+|x|^{2})^{0}g(x)|<\infty$.